How to make Apollo graphql request in Nextjs server component (using app directory)?
This is the code inside the page.tsx (i.e app/page.tsx):
import { client } from "@/GraphQL/apollo-client";
import { fetchJobs } from "@/GraphQL/queries";
import Jobs from "@/components/jobs";
import React from "react";

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const { data } = await client.query({ query: fetchJobs });
  const jobs = data?.jobs || [];

  return { props: { jobs } };
}

const page = ({ jobs }) => {
  console.log(jobs);
  return (
    <div>
      <Jobs jobs={jobs} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;

This is the code in Jobs component (i.e components/jobs.tsx):
import React from "react";
import { client } from "@/GraphQL/apollo-client";
import { fetchJobs } from "@/GraphQL/queries";
import { useSuspenseQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const Jobs = ({ jobs }) => {
  console.log({ jobs });

  return <div>jobs</div>;
};

export default Jobs;

Here im getting a error like below:
Failed to compile
× "getServerSideProps" is not supported in app/.

Then how to make a graphql request in server component in Nextjs?
I tried creating pages folder in the root directory and inside that i created a jobs folder and index.tsx file inside it (i.e rootdirectory/pages/jobs/index.js):
import { client } from "@/GraphQL/apollo-client";
import { fetchJobs } from "@/GraphQL/queries";

const Test = () => {
  return <div>page</div>;
};

export default Test;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: fetchJobs,
  });

  console.log("HEY", data);

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}

But here im not able to navigate to that jobs pages itself, getting 404 This page could not be found error
i also tried making a request inside Jobs component itself but here the getServerSideProps function is not getting executed and im not getting the "first" console.

const Jobs = () => {
  return <div>jobs</div>;
};

export default Jobs;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const { data } = await client.query({ query: fetchJobs });
  const jobs = data?.jobs || [];
  console.log("first");

  return { props: { jobs } };
}


According to Next.JS Docs:
In the pages directory, getServerSideProps is used to fetch data on the server and forward props to the default exported React component in the file. In app directory, you can make the component async and just do:
import { client } from "@/GraphQL/apollo-client";
import { fetchJobs } from "@/GraphQL/queries";
import Jobs from "@/components/jobs";
import React from "react";

const page = async () => {
  const { data } = await client.query({ query: fetchJobs });
  const jobs = data?.jobs || [];
  return (
    <div>
      <Jobs jobs={jobs} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;


Yes it's working thankyou

So does this mean the whole component becomes SSC and it will be better for SEO and web crawlers?

But we need to use getServerSideProps to get data on the server side right?
